# I'm getting the "mmc0: card never left busy state" for an SD card that Windows happily recognises and formats. What can I do to make it work on Linux?

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, steam-os

I went and bought a steam deck, and decided to get an SD card for it - a Hunyeiz thing from a Kodak shop. After a messy time accidentally formatting it poorly, hastily typing console commands given to me from Reddit in an attempt to format it manually, and repeatedly trying to reformat it, I'm in this exciting holding pattern where neither the deck or my linux partition on my computer acknowledge the card being entered into the system at all.

Checking dmesg gives me the
`mmc0: card never left busy state`
message.

Now, I understand that when this happens the card should be thrown in the bin - it's no longer good to anyone. But when I enter it into my Windows partition, it plays the little jingle and gives me the option to reformat it. Formatting it for windows works, and it's then given a nice drive name and label, and is openable in Explorer.
This has not changed how either linux machine treats it - both giving me the same message.

What can I do to make it work on Linux? Is there anything I can do? I don't really need an SD card for Windows (although maybe worst comes to worst I'll look into refunding it - I'm assuming most cameras etc will use it fine?)

I'll go over the steps I took to get the card in this state if it's helpful.

1. I inserted the card, went into the settings section of the steam deck, clicked on the **storage** tab, and saw my card registered. It prompted me to format the drive. I clicked that button. A loading screen appeared.
2. After some time, the loading screen disappeared. The SD card was also not being recognised in this tab. I restarted my deck.
3. The deck was taking a really long time to restart. I didn't know what was causing this, so after some googling decided to hard kill it by holding the power button for 6 seconds.
4. The SD card still wasn't showing up. I panicked and switched to the desktop mode, where it was listed but clicking on it would bring up an error message: `Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at (some path): wrong fa type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error` This seemed bad. I was worried at this point if I'd bricked the SD card from restarting too soon.
5. Googling pointed me towards trying to run an fsck on */dev/mmcblk0p1*. I ran it on */dev/mmcblk0* and got an error message I don't remember. I think it was trying to mount it and failing.
6. At this point, I found a quick hack to reset the drive - running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0`. I was told I could run it for a minute or so and then cancel it. I did that.
7. Restarting the machine again, I found the SD card was visible in the steam deck **storage** page again. Thinking my problem was that I restarted too early, I ran the format again. It did exactly the same thing as last time - the SD card vanished from the steam **storage** list.
8. I then swapped to the desktop mode again. The SD card was visible in the drive list again, but had the same error message as before when clicked -  `Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at (some path): wrong fa type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`. This was annoying - I assumed now that the steam deck's formatting system was causing this.
9. Googling, I found one random reddit post that recommended typing `sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1`, and hitting yes to all the prompts. I did this. It said that it successfuly formatted the drive and mentioned replacing the journal on the drive.
10. The SD card was now no longer showing up even in the mount section in desktop mode. I restarted. It still wasn't. I check dmesg and this is when I realised it was giving me the `mmc0: card never left busy state` message.
11. I was about to give up, but then I put the SD card into my windows partition and found it working perfectly. I thought maybe formatting on Windows and then reinserting it into the deck would work, but nothing changed - the steam deck and my linux partition don't even acknowledge its existence.

Anyway - thanks for reading! Is there anything I can do? If it was a hardware problem I'm unsure why it'd work just fine on a different operating system. It feels like I've just bricked the SD card, but again I want to believe I can fix this (it was expensive).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.